# How to assign width and height attr's in QuillJS/Rich-Text deltas

Tags: javascript, html, rich-text-editor, quill

We're using QuillJS 1.0 Beta. We have the text editor and the user initially creates the content. When they click submit, it extracts the `.innerHTML()` from the editor and saves it to our database. *Then*, if the user wants to edit that content, we pull the html from our database and use the `.pasteHTML()` from Quill's API to paste it into the editor.

When we paste the html into the editor, text styling is pasting just fine, but when we include images, the size of the image is being set to the natural height/width of the image instead of the inline-styling we have set. For some reason, Quill's cleaner must be removing this styling. Is there a parameter to pass in so that we can avoid this "cleaner" since we're passing in straight html?

Here's some of the html string that comes from the DB looks like:

```
<p class="ql-align-center"><strong class="ql-size-huge" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">&nbsp;$450 Referral Bonus</strong></p><p class="ql-align-center"><strong class="ql-size-small" style="color: rgb(186, 35, 35);">Phone a friend!</strong></p><p class="ql-align-center"><img width="145" height="140" style="width: 145px; height: 140px;" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG
```

As you can see, the styling is there. When I view the DOM after Quill paste's it into the editor, the img tag doesn't have any of those styles. Any idea?

I've tried to add a matcher that will interpret the image tag a certain way, but no matter what I do, I can't get the width/height to stick:

```
quill.editor.clipboard.addMatcher('IMG', function(node, delta) {
            let imgWidth = node.width;
            let imgHeight = node.height;
            var delta2 = new Delta([{
                insert: { image: node.src },
                attributes: {
                    width: imgWidth,
                    height: imgHeight
                }
            }]);

            return delta2;
        });
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem :(

Comment: It's a bug with the current release. I reached out to Jason and he confirmed. He was working on a fix so I'm assuming maybe next release it will be fixed. However, in the meantime I came up with a solution. If you target the container.innerHTML and just set that attribute to the html string, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks so much for reply, Can you provide sample code for it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the full HTML string with inline-styling on the images, paragraph tags, etc, you can just set the `quill.container.firstChild.innerHTML` property to the html string and it will paste it for you with the styles. This totally bypasses the `addMatcher` method and the `pasteHTML()` method.

In my case, I was getting the HTML string from our DB and setting that property to it:

```
this._httpClient.fetch('/ApiUrl')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(resp => {
                this.obj.editor.container.firstChild.innerHTML = resp.ExecutiveControlHtmlResult;
            });
```

I had my instance of Quill saved in a variable called `editor` however you should be able to just set these via jquery or whatever you're using.

Comment: Appreciate your answer !! In my use case i am inserting at cursor position using getSelection and rang.index than pastHTML. In this method i am able to insert tag at cursor position but style is lost. How can be achieve inserting html at cursor position and maintaining it style using ur code.

Comment: @PradeepJaiswar Don't use Quill's pasteHTML() method. If you're wanting to paste some html into the editor, just set the property "quill.container.firstChild.innerHTML" to the HTML. Quill's pasteHTML method strips the inline styling.